# Append unique value to url in Jquery function to prevent Internet Explorer caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Under Chrome, Safari and Firefox the below function works fine, but under IE I believe its caching the page and doesn't actually refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#checkuser').fadeOut('slow').load('chat_check.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 15000);
</script>

<div id="checkuser" style="width:1px;height:1px;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Now I want to append a string to the url so IE doesnt cache the page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(

    fetch_unix_timestamp = function() { return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10)) }

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();

    function()
    {
    $('#checkuser').fadeOut('slow').load('chat_check.php?t='+timestamp).fadeIn("slow");
    }, 15000);
    </script>
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong with appending the timestamp variable to the url. I need the fix.

TIA

WORKING CODE BELOW:

In IE I had to wrap everything in $(document).ready(function() and add $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });.

Seems to be the only way to prevent IE from caching the page. The meta tags dont work with IE9 to prevent caching. Anyway, here's the working code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#checkuser').load('chat_check.php');
}, 15000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong? The way you initialize `timestamp` is a bit, um, odd but what wrong thing is happening?

Comment: on ie use the developers tool press f12, then click on the network tab and then click start capturing to see wether ie is caching the request or nt

Comment: `parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))` works fine here.  It'sa bit of an odd way to do it, but it seems to work.  You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2qav4/

Comment: under IE the database is never updated with the user's info and only under IE. is that the correct syntax for my javascript ?

Comment: under the network tab, ie isnt loading the url at all

Comment: Whats the way to wrap this in <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to prevent IE from caching the JQuery request is with AJAX it seems

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#checkuser').load('chat_check.php');
}, 15000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this:

```
var timestamp = Date.now().toString();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Betuf/

Answer (score 0):

Converting the timestamp into integer is not required, try the belwo code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(

    fetch_unix_timestamp = function() { return (new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10)); }

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();

    function()
    {
    $('#checkuser').fadeOut('slow').load('chat_check.php?t='+timestamp).fadeIn("slow");
    }, 15000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a semicolon `;` after the return statement.

Comment: where should i put the semicolon ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function(){
            var timestamp = parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10));
            $('#checkuser').fadeOut('slow').load('chat_check.php?t='+timestamp).fadeIn("slow");
        },
        15000
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: IE still wont load that...I'll have to wrap this in a Jquery function i bet